# Is it possible to simply pass a generic method with generic parameters as an argument to another method in C#?

Tags: c#

For a test, I want to create a generic "helper" method which will take take two arguments, the first argument is a function (or a reference to the function) and the 2nd argument is a list of objects for that function that are to be called as its parameters.

The following does this perfectly:

```
CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease(new Func<int, int>(MyMethod), new object[] {1});

public static int CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease(Delegate func, params object[] args)
{
  func.DynamicInvoke(args);
  return 3;
}
```

The thing is, this doesn't look very nice when calling it and I wish to abstract it into another method to act as syntatic sugar.

Ideally I want it to be called like this:

```
CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease(myMethod, new Object[] {1});
```

From what I can gather, there is no elegant solution to do this in C# since I cannot pass myMethod by itself as a reference anywhere, instead I must pass it by declaring a new Func along with the return type of the method. Since I'm not using this return type anywhere, I'm not sure why it's necessary to input this information. My limited understanding is that because C# is statically typed, the compiler must know everything and things like this just aren't possible.

Is this true or not? How would I create syntatic sugar to simply pass a method to another method which can be called there without needing to invoke "new Func"? I would have thought simply passing the function as a reference pointer would allow me to do this, but I'm having difficultly doing this too. I looked into delegates, using "unsafe" with pointers, and a few other options. None of them seem to make this possible, or if they do, they didn't explain it in a manner that I could understand.

I simply want to pass a method to another method, and invoke it with a variable list of object params with variable length whereby I don't need to specify this whilst invoking it. I'm not sure if I'm trying to force C# to do something it's not meant to do here, and instead I'd be better off using a dynamically typed language to do this. The problem is I really enjoy the intellisense that the static typing of C# offers, along with the performance improvements over a language like Python. I'd just like a way to syntactically abstract away the boilerplate with my own helper methods for things like this.

UPDATE: Thanks to the comments here it seems I can do this with a lambda expression nice and elegantly. The signature can be simply changed to `public static long CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease<T>(Func<T> func)`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with this... *why* do you want to do that?

Comment: Any reason you can't simply pass a `Func<int>` to your method. e.g. `CallMyMethod(() => MyMethod(a, b, c, ...))`.

Comment: Funcs and lambdas should already be capable of doing whatever it is that you're attempting here.

Comment: @Ian Mercer Interesting, so would I just change the signature to public static int CallMyMethod<T>(Func<T> func, params object[] args) to make it generic for any params type of any length? I'm new to C# and have yet to appreciate these lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If deferred execution is what you want simply pass a `Func<TReturnType>` to your method (or class). The calling method doesn't need to know how many parameters are involved.

e.g.  Assuming MyMethod has a signature `int MyMethod(int arg)`:

```
CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease(() => MyMethod(1));

public static int CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease(Func<int> func)
{
   return func();
}
```

If `MyMethod` takes two parameters, it's the same call:

```
CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease(() => MyMethod(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want. It looks like I can make it even more generic by making the signature "public static int CallMyFunctionWithParamsPlease<T>(Func<T> func)" then any arbitrary function can be passed it seems.

Comment: For variable Length of Arguments, there is no other way then your delegate.Invoke().
But for convenience, you should support any form of Func<T>, Func<T1, T2>, Func<T1, T2, T3>, Action<T>,Action<>, etc.

Comment: @Holger only if you care about using those parameters inside the method too. If all you care about is the result you can capture them outside the method in the lambda.

Comment: That's right, it's double wrapped here, and 3 functions are called. Just if it's `int MyMethod()` you can skip the lambda ...to say something useful.